# Trigonometric inequality on triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality

Prove that this inequality holds for all triangles $ABC$:

$$\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}\leq\frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: This is a fairly standard inequality. What have you tried?

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/InequalitiesInTriangle.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=90°-A,y=90°-B,z=90°-C$. Then $x+y+z=90°$

Then, $$\cos A\cos B\cos C=\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)=\sin(x)\sin(y)\cos(x+y)\\={1\over2}(\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y))\cos(x+y)$$

$$\large\leq {1\over2}\left({\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)+\cos(x+y)\over 2}\right)^2 \leq {1\over 8}$$

The first inequality part comes from $\left({m+n\over 2}\right)^2\geq mn$ for any $m,n$

Comment: You should change the notations $a,b,c$. Because in any triangle $\Delta ABC$, $A,B,C$ are assumed to be the three angles, and $a,b,c$ are assumed to be the three sides. You can assume here as, $x=90°-A,y=90°-B,z=90°-C$, or something else. And for $degree$ sign, press $\color{red}{alt+248}$

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I have been trying to use this prove, but got stuck half way because I forget to use AM-GM. Thanks..

Comment: @Subhadeep Dey I have changed the notations.

Comment: @user153077 In fact the inequality part does not come from $AM-GM$ but rather from $(m-n)^2\geq 0$. It does not require $m$ and $n$ to be positive.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=\cos A\cos B\cos C$

$2y=\cos A\{\cos(B-C)-\cos A\}$ as $\cos(B+C)=\cos(\pi-A)=-\cos A$

$\iff\cos^2A-\cos A\cos(B-C)+2y=0$

As $\cos A$ is real, $\cos^2(B-C)-8y\ge0\iff8y\le\cos^2(B-C)\le1$

The equality occurs if $\cos(B-C)=1\iff B=C$

Then $\cos A=\dfrac12\implies A=\dfrac\pi3$

$\implies B=C=\dfrac{B+C}2=\dfrac{\pi-\dfrac\pi3}2=A$

Comment: How can you get $\cos^2(B-C)-8y\geq 0$

Comment: We can use calculus to show that $f(A,B)=-\cos A \cos B \cos (A+B)$ has a unique  maximum at $A=B=\pi/3 $ over the range $0\leq A\leq \pi\wedge 0\leq B\leq \pi\wedge A+B\leq \pi$.

Comment: @user153077, See http://everythingmaths.co.za/maths/grade-11/02-equations-and-inequalities/02-equations-and-inequalities-06.cnxmlplus

Comment: @user254665,  We can safely avoid calculus if we simply apply discriminant property of Quadratic Eqution

Comment: Of course.But it's a good introductory exercise.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: use the law of cosine and the inequality with $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle: $(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b) \leq abc$ ,which is easy to prove using AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
$$ A+B+C= \pi$$

Max value occurs when the triangle is equilateral due to symmetry.

$$ A = B = C= \pi/3 ,\;  \cos A = \cos B = \cos C =1/2 $$

The maximum value can only be $$ (1/2)^3= 1/8.$$

Comment: Can you prove it?